# proper way to replace NaN value from another dataframe on column match in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm newbie to pandas, and trying to  replace a column value (NaN) in df1 with df2 with column value match. And facing the following error.

```
df1
unique_col  |  Measure
944537          NaN
7811403         NaN 
8901242114307     1 

df2
unique_col  |  Measure
944537           18
7811403          12 
8901242114307    17.5



df1.loc[(df1.unique_col.isin(df2.unique_col) &
                       df1.Measure.isnull()), ['Measure']] = df2[['Measure']]
```

I have a two dataframes with 3 million records and on performing below operation facing the following error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You way to easily fill nans is to use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function. In your case, if you have the dfs as (notice the indexes)

```
    unique_col      Measure
0   944537          NaN
1   7811403         NaN
2   8901242114307   1.0


    unique_col      Measure
0   944537          18.0
1   7811403         12.0
2   8901242114307   17.5
```

You can simply

```
>>> df.fillna(df2)


    unique_col       Measure
0   944537           18.0
1   7811403          12.0
2   8901242114307    1.0
```

If indexes are *not* the same as the above, you can *set them to be the same* and use the same function

```
df = df.set_index('unique_col')
df.fillna(df2.set_index('unique_col'))
```